# Shell in emacs displays names of variables by preceding them \200\230

Tags: shell, emacs

When i run a compile instruction from the shell/eshell/term in emacs , the names of the variables appear weird in the shell .

Here is a sample code (with some random error) and the output when I compile :

```
#include iostream
#include cstdlib


int main (void)
{
cscdsd ;//some random error 
return ;
}
//shell o/p:
g++ new.cc 
new.cc: In function â\200\230int main()â\200\231:
new.cc:7: error: â\200\230cscdsdâ\200\231 was not declared in this scope
new.cc:8: error: return-statement with no value, in function returning â\200\230intâ\200\231
~/codes $
```

What i have figured out is that \200\230 and \200\231 mean the start and end of a variable or function name . 
Any ideas what this happens or how to get rid of it ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`\200` is an octal escape sequence.  In hex, `â\200\230` is `E2 80 98`, which is how U+2018 (LEFT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK) is encoded in UTF-8.  Likewise, `â\200\231` is U+2019 (RIGHT SINGLE QUOTATION MARK).  This is what happens when `g++` emits UTF-8 and Emacs interprets it as ISO-8859-1.

You probably need to set `default-process-coding-system` to a different value.  Try (in your ~/.emacs):

```
(setq default-process-coding-system '(utf-8-unix . utf-8-unix))
```

There are other ways to tell Emacs what coding system to expect.  Read the documentation for the variables `default-process-coding-system` & `process-coding-system-alist` and the functions `universal-coding-system-argument` & `set-buffer-process-coding-system`.

Answer (score 1):

Text encoding should be part of `LANG` environment variable.
`export LANG=en_US.UTF-8` should fix.
On Ubuntu systems, change it in `/etc/default/locale`.